# PHP variable inside Google Analytics Code

Tags: php, javascript, html, google-analytics

I have the following code

```
if ($form_id == 1)
{

    $form_name = "Test form 1";
}
elseif ($form_id == 2)
{
    $form_name = "General Enquiries";
}
else
{
    // do something
}
```

I now need to echo $form_name within this bit of code but cant seem to be able to get it to show.

```
<form id="form_7" class="appnitro" action="#main_body" method="post" onSubmit="_gaq.push(['_trackPageview', '/virtual/general-enquiries']);">
```

The bit that says **/virtual/general-enquiries** needs to be replace by the php echo.

Thanks
Roy

Comment: <form id="form_7" class="appnitro" action="#main_body" method="post" onSubmit="_gaq.push(['_trackPageview', '<?php echo $form_name; ?>']);">

Comment: "I have a problem. Fix it for me. kthxbai"

Comment: Hi still cant get it to work.

Comment: Hi

I still cant get this to work. Looking at the html its showing this.

<form id="form_7" class="appnitro"  method="post" action="#main_body" onSubmit="_gaq.push(['_trackPageview', '<?php echo ; ?>']);">

I have this at the top of the php file


$formid = '{$form->id}';
if ($formid == 7)
{
$form_name = "Test form 1";
}
elseif ($formid == 2)
{
$form_name = "General Enquiries";
}
else
{
    // do something
}

In the script they are using this to produce form_7

<form id="form_{$form->id}"

So not sure why is coming up blank still.

Thanks
Roy

Comment: Hi

Even this bit of code returns back nothing.

   <form id="form_{$form->id}" class="appnitro" {$form_enc_type} method="post" action="#main_body" method="post" onSubmit="_gaq.push(['_trackPageview', '<?php 
  $form_name= "Test";
  echo $form_name; ?>']);">
            {$form_desc_div}      
   <ul {$ul_class}>
   {$form->error_message}
   {$all_element_markup}
   {$custom_element}
   {$button_markup}
   </ul>
  </form>

Answer (score 0):

It does need to be echoed by PHP. The server-side code will be interpreted long before Google Analytics code gets interpreted on the client. Something like this should work for you:

```
<?php
if ($form_id == 1)
{

    $form_name = "Test form 1";
}
elseif ($form_id == 2)
{
    $form_name = "General Enquiries";
}
else
{
    // do something
}

if(isset($form_name))
{
    echo '<form id="' . $form_id . '" class="appnitro" action="#main_body" method="post" onSubmit="_gaq.push([\'_trackPageview\', \'' . $form_name . '\']);">';
}
```

Answer (score -1):

This will do it:

```
"...onSubmit="_gaq.push(['_trackPageview', '<? echo $form_name; ?>']);"
```